# Add to the end of datamapper json

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I was wondering how to add another key value pair to the end of the JSON generated by DataMappers `.to_json` method. When I try to call `to_json(:methods => [:total_pages])`, it ignores the methods bit all together.

I would like it to produce something like this:

```
{
  'data':        [rows go here],
  'total_pages': X
}
```

Is there a way to just do the method inline or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simpler.

```
{
    data:   YourModel.your_whatever,
    total_pages: YourModel.total_pages
}.to_json
```

DM serialization to_json tries to call methods provided in options on the same object it is called itself (in your case - probably collection of results, that does not have total_pages method defined)

Answer (score 2):

You could edit the JSON string, but as far as I know there's no easy way to inject arbitrary values into the JSON.

Calling `your_dm_resource.to_json(:methods => [:total_pages])` is the correct way to do what you want, check your `some_dm_resource.total_pages` method is working that way you expect.

And if you're using a modern Ruby, you can drop the hash rockets:

```
your_dm_resource.to_json(methods: [:total_pages])
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have been fiddling around with the total_pages method, and I can't get it to work when I have it as a class method (it has a bit of a fit probably because of the relations). Do you know if it's possible to reference a local function in the to_json arguments, or does it have to be a symbol?